# How can I wait for a form submission and reload using selenium and Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using Selenium for JavaScript and I am running into an issue on a page whereby I need to submit multiple items into a form and each time submit the form. The issue is that I need to wait for the page to briefly reload after each "submission" of the form. This reload breaks what I have. Typically the behavior I get is that 2 items will end up from my loop into the fields before the first "submit" press is detected. I need to fill out the fields, submit and then briefly wait while the item is added as a row to the page on a refresh. I've tried accomplishing this in JavaScript directly and also via Selenium by experimenting with the various waits but I haven't had any luck getting this to properly work.

Here's my current Selenium code

```
let field1 = await driver.findElement(By.name('field1'))
  let field2 = await driver.findElement(By.name('field2'))
  let field3 = await driver.findElement(By.name('field3'))
  let field4 = await driver.findElement(By.name('field4')) 

  ctn.Items.forEach(async (item, index) => {
   field1.sendKeys(item.number)
    field2.sendKeys(item.name)
   // field3.sendKeys("value", item.type) // Not working
                           
    field4.sendKeys(item.description)
   
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="item"]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/input[1]')).click()
```

So, after each click I need to wait for the form submission to go through before the next iteration of the loop begins to refill the fields. As I noted in the code above as well, setting a field value doesn't seem to be working. I would be ok if someone could help me accomplish this in Javascript directly by using the `executeScript()` method but it would be nice to do it directly in Selenium. Can anyone confirm how to do this in Selenium or JS? These issues seem to be perhaps easier in the Java or Python version, I haven't seen a whole lot on Selenium for JS and it appears to be missing some things compared to other versions.

Comment: FYI the reason you don't see much selenium for javascript is because people are using puppeteer / playwright which is more modern

Comment: can you share the url of the page please